# Non-programming question used as "good content" in close vote audit

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, disputed-review-audits

I just [failed an audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/17632999) question with [Line of Business Apps not installable - “This app has been blocked due to company policy”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46283255/line-of-business-apps-not-installable-this-app-has-been-blocked-due-to-compan)

However this looks to be way off-topic, as it is not programming-related so far as I can see.

Vote to close?

Comment: Yeah, I've seen a lot of this lately. "Ooh, I like this question so *upvote*", not realizing their actions are destructive

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Vote to close?

YES! This is a question that should be taken up with the software creators, as it appears to be a bug report. Thus, it does not belong on Stack Overflow.

Since you seem to be new to the disputed audit corner, allow me to reference [this excerpt from the FAQ on audits:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/335772)

> **The system expected me to positively review a bad post**
>
> - The most common case is when a low-quality, off-topic, or otherwise close-worthy post gets upvoted. Sometimes visitors may upvote posts without paying attention to the site rules.

Comment: Note that downvoting and voting to close is very important when you come across an invalid audit, because that not only addresses the problem of an off-topic question, but it removes the post as an audit candidate.