# What is the meaning of "I just failed an audit question"?

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits

I have seen that a few meta question start with "I just failed an audit question....."

Ex question : [Non-programming question used as audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357868/non-programming-question-used-as-audit?cb=1)

What is the meaning of it? It means they just skip the question on review queue?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/review-audits/info | https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121 to learn what's an audit.

Comment: About skipping :  "skip the question" is always safe to do. It doesn't count towards the review stats, and will never trigger anything (excepted skip this current review). **skip review is always a valid option when in doubt.**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An audit is a fake review case for a user who is [helping with peer review on the site](https://stackoverflow.com/review).  Categories of peer review include reviewing edits made by low-rep users, reviewing first posts by new users, reviewing decisions to close or re-open questions, and reviewing very-low-quality/not-an-answer flags, plus a few others.

These audits or fake review cases are chosen, ideally, for having an obvious, correct choice.  The idea is to detect inattentive, willfully negligent, malicious, or non-conforming reviewers, rebuke them, slow them down for a moment to think about what they did, and hope they'll get back to work doing the job right.

Some reviewers are [automatically banned from reviewing for failing too many of these audits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271233).  And, sadly, some reviewers deserve these bans for clicking the same review response over and over to speed up the process of getting certain badges that are given out for doing a few hundred or a thousand reviews.  Anyways, the beatings will continue until morale improves.

The problem with the audits is that some of them are outliers.  The audits, you see, are chosen through machine filtering.  And an answer might have had 10 upvotes, and in the audit they ask you if it is 'not an answer' and indeed it is a link-only answer. And so you click to recommend deletion of the answer, and then, BOOM!, it says you weren't paying attention!

Since audits are chosen algorithmically, you may be able to remove some outliers from the audit pool by voting on them directly.  For example, you can downvote a question that had all upvotes (and thus, was presumed 'good' by the algorithm and eligible as an audit question).

**See also: [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work)**